# How can I detect when a property changes on a service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want components to be able to subscribe or be notified of a change on a variable in a service.

I looked into Observables but I don't think this would work because you need to complete the stream and I need to know about changes the variable over the entire time the component is active.

Does anyone know a good strategy for this?

Comment: Why would you want a variable to change inside a service? Services are typically used to fetch server data, validate user input, or log directly to the console. While a good component presents properties and methods for data binding. So make another component where you change the variable and track that.. (Src: https://angular.io/guide/architecture)

Comment: Because I check whether the user is logged in and when the state changes I update for all components

Comment: Okay..I would suggest to create a component that fetches if user is logged in or not, and if it is; then call service from this component that updates all other components..

Comment: Yes but how would I call a method on all other components?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382716/call-other-components-function-in-angular-2-using-typescript This might help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) or any of its variations?

Example using `BehaviorSubject`

Service:

```
export class MyService {
  myVariableSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  increase() {
    this.myVariableSubject.next(this.myVariableSubject.value + 1);
  }
}
```

Component:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.myVariableSubject.subscribe((value: number) => console.log(value));
}
```

Warning: This might not be the most suitable solution to your problem (which you never state).

Comment: Perfect this is exactly it. Thanks